# how can i recall data from an SQL table TEXT field into and HTML textarea using PHP? (all part of a simple Article Management System)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, return-value

I building my own simple article management system, and have run into a bit of trouble upon creating a page to edit the articles.

I am able to recall the title and tagline of the articles in the form input using the 'value' attribute.

However, I am yet to work out how to do the same thing with the form textarea as it has no 'value' attribute.

Also, can the same be done with a dropdown menu in the HTML form select?

Answer (score 1):

The `textarea` input type does not have a value field, the value must be placed within the tag itself.  For example:

`<textarea>Here are the contents of the textarea</textarea>`

To populate the select field, the syntax would be:

`<select>
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
</select>`

Comment: cheers, I have used the php echo to return the values in the input fields and have done as suggested for the textarea using a similar echo, but i get no data returned.

Am I using incorrect php functions or something?

Comment: can you post some of your php and the html it generates?  you will probably also want to escape your output using htmlspecialchars.

Comment: Here is my php from the body of the page (I'll post the form as a separate comment because its too big to all fit here):

<?php
....get files....

// Create an instance of DbConnector
$connector = new DbConnector();

// Check whether a form has been submitted. If so, carry on
if ($_POST){

....Validate form...

$insertQuery = "UPDATE cmsarticles (title,tagline,section,thearticle)  VALUES (".
"'".$_POST['title']."', ".
"'".$_POST['tagline']."', ".
$_POST['section'].", ".
"'".addslashes($_POST['thearticle'])."')";

.... save form....
?>

Comment: <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>">
        <p>&nbsp;Title:
          <input name="title" type="text" id="title" value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>">
          </p>
        <p>&nbsp;Tagline:
          <input name="tagline" type="text" id="tagline" value="<?php echo $row['tagline']; ?>">
          </p>

Comment: <p>&nbsp;Section:
          <select name="section" id="section">
            
            <?PHP  // Generate a drop-down list of sections.
    // NOTE : Requires database modifications in article 4

    $result = $connector->query('SELECT ID,name FROM cmssections ORDER BY name');

    // Get an array containing the results.
    // Loop for each item in that array
    while ($row = $connector->fetchArray($result)){
     echo $row['section'];
     echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
            </select>
          </p>

Comment: <p>&nbsp;Article:
          <textarea name="thearticle" cols="50" rows="12" id="thearticle"><?php echo $row['thearticle']; ?></textarea>
          </p>
        <p align="center">
          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">
          </p>
        </form>

Comment: I suspect your $row variable does not contain what you think it does.  You can use var_dump($row) to view the contents.